# Why does my closed LinkedIn account still show up on Google searches?

Tags: google-search, linkedin

I thought I closed my LinkedIn account...so why is it still showing up on Google searches?

Answer (score 1):

The databases where the information regarding your closed account don't update regularly and unfortunately, the data retention of the closed account might remain and still propagate in web-wide data sharing processes.
It should begin to correct as various web spiders and bots used to recheck locations online report back that there is no account at the previous address.

Sorry that things are not instantly updated but, eventually the systems where the info is saved will not get it in their updates and it will fall out.

Hope this helps explain why data can persist even when it no longer exists for as long as it does.  Let us know.